# How to limit fps output in MPlayer?

Tags: video, mplayer

Is there any way to limit fps of the video played by mplayer?

Let's say, I want to play a video at 1 fps because I need it for experimental tests. What option do I need to put ? And, if this is imposible, is there anything I can do to limit the fps ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `--fps` option, but keep in mind that this doesn't work with `--correct-pts` which is now default for most of the formats:

```
mplayer --no-correct-pts --fps=1 somefile.ogv
```

Alternatively, you can change the framerate by setting a `fixpts` video filter:

```
mplayer --vf=fixpts=fps=1 somefile.ogv
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mplayer -fps 1 my_video.mkv
```

Should do what you want: play the video at one frame per second.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've tried the command, but I can't see any difference between 1fps and normal playback.

Comment: Same here, does not seem to work.